# Snaplogic: How to join two tables with a condition other than equals (like, >, <)

Tags: snaplogic

I am trying to join two tables in which column from table 1 "contains" data from one of the columns in table 2 i.e. consider below hypothetical:

- Table **error_log**:

  ```
  id| description
  1 | this is right, bla bla, bla
  2 | this is , bla bla, bla, wrong
  3 | this is , bla bla, bla, a disaster, , bla bla, bla
  4 | bla, bla, bla
  ```
- Table **result_type**:

  ```
  id|type
   1|Right
   2|Wrong
   3|Disaster
  ```

Now, I wish to join these two tables and store the results in 3rd table i.e.

- Table **analysis**:

  ```
   id|error_log_id|result_type_id
   1 | 1          | 1
   2 | 2          | 2
   3 | 3          | 3
   4 | 4          | null
  ```

Normally, in any RDBMS, I can do this pretty easily with a left join with a like condition i.e.

```
select e.error_log_id, r.result_type_id from error_log e 
left join result_type r on e.description like '%'+ r.type +'%'
```

but I can't seem to find to do so through snaplogic? I tried Snap Join, but it only provides equals join condition i.e.
[image]

any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of records in `result_type` doesn't change that often and is a lot smaller than the number of records in `error_log`, you could use `In-memory Lookup` snap instead of the `Join` snap. That aside, there is no straight forward way of doing this using regular snaps. I would suggest doing complicated queries in the database whenever possible. Following is an implementation using the `Script` snap.

**Sample Pipeline**

[image]

**In-memory Lookup**

Add a field called `join_id` (or whatever) with the value `1` (or whatever) and join based on this field in the lookup. This will add the whole lookup (in your case, the types) in all the incoming documents.

[image]

**Script**

```
try { load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js"); } catch(e) { }

importPackage(com.snaplogic.scripting.language);

importClass(java.util.ArrayList);
importClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap);

var impl = {
    
    input : input,
    output : output,
    error : error,
    log : log,

    execute : function () {
       this.log.info("Executing Transform Script");
        while (this.input.hasNext()) {
            try {
                var inDoc = this.input.next();
                var outDocs = new ArrayList();

                var errorLogId = inDoc.id;
                var description = inDoc.description;
                var types = inDoc.types;
                var flag = false;
                for(var idx in types) {
                    var type = types[idx];
                    if(description.toLowerCase().contains(type.type.toLowerCase())) {
                        var outDoc = new LinkedHashMap();
                        outDoc.put('error_log_id', errorLogId);
                        outDoc.put('result_type_id', type.id);
                        outDocs.add(outDoc);
                    }
                }

                if(outDocs.isEmpty()) {
                    var outDoc = new LinkedHashMap();
                    outDoc.put('error_log_id', errorLogId);
                    outDoc.put('result_type_id', null);
                    outDocs.add(outDoc);
                }

                for(var idx in outDocs) {
                    var outDoc = outDocs[idx];
                    this.output.write(inDoc, outDoc);
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                var errDoc = new LinkedHashMap();
                errDoc.put("error", err);
                this.log.error(err);
                this.error.write(errDoc);
            }
        }
        this.log.info("Script executed");
    },
    
    cleanup : function () {
       this.log.info("Cleaning up")
    }
};

var hook = new com.snaplogic.scripting.language.ScriptHook(impl);
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bilesh. Yes I tried similar approach. Used Gate snap to collect all the types in an array and then joined the array to main stream with condition 1=1, thereby adding extra column containing this array for each row and then used Json splitter to flaten the main stream into no. of items in array. Will post the answer shortly

Comment: I've never used `script` snap before, great suggestion.

Comment: @ManishMishra Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct snap, try changing the ‘Join type’ to the relevant value, such as Outer.